# Refresh just one row in a gridview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a gridview that is populated with an object of type List  and whenever I do an update the whole gridview is refreshed.
This would not be a problem with few records, but with many the process becomes quite slow ... Is there any way to refresh the gridview but only by updating the row that was changed?

Here is my code:

```
            if (DaIncrementa(artigo) == true)
            {
                Update(Convert.ToInt32(et.Text),true);
                aberto = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Update(Convert.ToInt32(et.Text),false);
                aberto = false;
            }

            FillDataNaoContados(familia);

            IParcelable gridViewState = gvContagem.OnSaveInstanceState();

            gvContagem.Adapter = new TextAdapter(this, artigos);

            gvContagem.OnRestoreInstanceState(gridViewState);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No there is not , you can use `RecycerView` with `gridLayotManager` instead of `gridView` and use `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged()` to update a row or `adapter.notifyItemChanged()` to notify just one cell ,